# ListLinePlot's Interpolation method

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I Interpolated some oscillating data points using  `ListLinePlot[]` , and set the  `InterpolatingOrder->10` . This gives a nice plot that fits my results very well. However, I am curious what the Interpolating Method is? I did not specify any  `Method` . What is the default method when interpolating `ListLinePlot[]` ?

Comment: From the [documentation of `InterpolationOrder`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolationOrder.html): "`InterpolationOrder -> n` specifies that polynomials of degree $n$ should be fitted between data points."

Comment: yes but my question is what method does the ListLinePlot use in doing the interpolation?

Comment: It's using a piecewise polynomial interpolation like what `Interpolation[]` uses.

Comment: Is it Spline or Hermite specifically? Or does Mathematica decide on it's own the optimal method? Sorry if this is an elementary question, I'm still learning this program..